# how to connect android to node.js file on server

Tags: android, html, node.js

I've searched and tried everything I've found but nothing seems to work. I can't begin to show what I've tried as there are too many different approaches.

I want to create an android app, which runs on company server, using node.js. I've found a tutorial on how to use html and JavaScript on the app, but I don't want it doing the work on the client side.

What I'm trying to do is have perhaps the html on the app to simply connect to a .js file on the server which will in turn call the files for the different actions/events. At the moment it's simply to return a field from the database which I can do in the .js file itself, I just can't get android to connect to it.

Can someone tell me the most straight forward way to approach this?

I'm a newbie to android so I'm trying to use node as I'm comfortable with it.

Comment: You need to learn about HTTP and REST.

Comment: I'm comfortable enough with the HTTP but I can't seem to find a good REST tutorial. Any advice on a good one?